# Cancel automatic login with key combination

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

I was asked to set up a PC with automatically logs in to a user account that's secured with several settings including blocked USB ports.

But whenever an Administrator has to log in to do maintenance, the automatic login on startup should be cancelled.

Is there a way to cancel the automatic login with a key combination?

I can't log out of the session because the USB ports are disabled, so I have neither keyboard nor mouse access to the system once it is logged in.

OS: Windows 7 Embedded Standard x64.

Comment: Any reason you can't simply log out of the restricted session when needing to do system maintenance?

Comment: Because the usb ports on the user account have to be disabled so the usb mouse and keyboard wont work

Comment: Well, that's certainly a valid use case for what you are asking. I edited your question to make it more clear; feel free to [edit] further if you want to.

Comment: I would expect that the typical technique for managing this kind of locked-down kiosk system would be via the network. VNC, RDP, Puppet, whatever. You could probably consider this to be more secure as well, since you could remove access to the USB ports at the hardware or driver level. So even if someone reboots the system and tries to type a keyboard combination, they won't get access to a login screen.